# macOS Catalina: point /bin/sh to a different shell

Tags: macos, bash, shell, dash

I need some Bash 4.x features in my shell on macOS Catalina, and my scripts must run on Dash `/bin/sh`, which by default points to Bash 3.x.

However, there seems no way to point Dash to my homebrew Bash under `/usr/local/bin`.

`chsh` can only specify default shell but cannot point a specific shell to another shell.

I used to hack with `mv` and `ln`, but since Apple tightened user permission since Catalina, that road is blocked as well.

Please help.

Comment: Does using `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` not solve your issue?

Comment: I ended up using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, but still wonder if redirecting Dash to custom Bash is possible.